# How to export files to wso2 ESB vfs proxy from a ServiceClient client?

Tags: wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB can down load the remote files by VFS transport, but how does a client to export a file to WSO2 ESB VFS server without FTP server or any file upload WS API? Does WSO2 ESB support VFS server?

If I already create a vfs proxy, could I export files by this proxy from a ServiceClient client??

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what Ratha said but you will also need to enable the VFS transports in order to use VFS in your proxy services created under the WSO2 ESB.

You can do that by going to **Configure** menu tab on the left of the WSO2 ESB's dashboard, select **Transports** and hit Enable on Lister and Sender under VFS Transport (depending which one you will use in your proxies - it's safe to have both enabled though). Hope it helps.

The following proxy service is listening for a folder called *in* on an SFTP location and copying back to the SFTP in *copied* folder:

```xml
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SFTPtry" transports="vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
 <target>
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full" />
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" />
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="vfs:sftp://user:password@your.ftp.site.com:22/copied" />
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://user:password@your.ftp.site.com:22/in</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://user:password@your.ftp.site.com:22/out</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:sftp://user:password@your.ftp.site.com:22/fail</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

define endpoint with vfs endpoint and send messages..

Edit: You may try like this;

```xml
 <proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="vfs:ftp://test@localhost/out?vfs.passive=true"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
                <drop/>
            </inSequence>
        </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not create above proxy in my ESB, the Faulty Service message:
Unable to configure the service StockQuoteProxy for the VFS transport: Service doesn't have configuration information for transport vfs. This service is being marked as faulty and will not be available over the VFS transport.